# CSS animations are not working in Github wiki pages

Tags: html, css, github, markdown, css-animations

I am trying to write the wiki for this project on Github.  I want the wiki to involve CSS animations, but none of the animations appear on the wiki page.

When I edit the Markdown sources using Visual Studio Code the animations work look great in the Markdown preview window.  But for some reason, they do not appear on the actual Github wiki's webpage, which suggests to me that it might be some deeper issue with Github's compatibility with CSS animations

Here are the relevant parts of the style sheet:

```css
canvas {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.dash {
    -webkit-animation-name: dash;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: dash;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    0%      { background: url(dashAnimation/frame1.png); }
    29%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame1.png); }

    30%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame2.png); }
    59%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame2.png); }

    60%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame3.png); }
    79%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame3.png); }

    80%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame4.png); }
    85%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame5.png); }
    90%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame6.png); }
    100%    { background: url(dashAnimation/frame7.png); }
}

@keyframes dash {
    0%      { background: url(dashAnimation/frame1.png); }
    29%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame1.png); }

    30%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame2.png); }
    59%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame2.png); }

    60%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame3.png); }
    79%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame3.png); }

    80%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame4.png); }
    85%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame5.png); }
    90%     { background: url(dashAnimation/frame6.png); }
    100%    { background: url(dashAnimation/frame7.png); }
}
```

This is the actual markdown source code that should be displayed on the "Player" wiki page:

```
<link href="resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<canvas class="dash"></canvas>
```

Finally, here's a [link](https://github.com/BenjiBoy926/Flight/wiki/Player) to the actual wiki page.  As you can see, the webpage displays absolutely nothing.  But there *should* be a fun little animation playing because of the `<canvas>` tag in the markdown source file

The basic idea is to attach the different `.class` HTML attributes to different animations, and then just change the `class="class-name"` attribute of the `<canvas>` tag to change the animation that is displayed.  This strategy works wonders in Visual Studio Code's Markdown preview window, but does not show up in the Github wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never work on GitHub.com for security reasons.

Github's HTML sanitizer is striping out both the `<link>` and `<canvas>` tags. If you use your browsers "view source" or "inspect" tools you can see that the wrapping `<div>` is completely empty. Starting on line 957 of the HTML source for that page we find:

```html
<div id="wiki-body" class="mt-4 flex-auto min-width-0 gollum-markdown-content instapaper_body">
    <div class="markdown-body">


    </div>

</div>
```

Note that the inner `<div>` is completely empty, with no content at all. For comparison, the same section of the HTML source for the [other page](https://github.com/BenjiBoy926/Flight/wiki) in your wiki looks like this:

```
<div id="wiki-body" class="mt-4 flex-auto min-width-0 gollum-markdown-content instapaper_body">
    <div class="markdown-body">
      <p>Welcome to the Flight wiki!</p>
<p>Here, you will find a formal description of the mechanics of the game, as well as some ideas about putting those mechanics together into challenging and compelling level designs.</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Clearly the HTML output of your Markdown content is contained in that `<div>`. So, we know we are looking at the correct location.

This can be verified as GitHub publishes their markup handing code. For starters, the README of [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup) lists HTML sanitation as step 2 of a 5 step process. Previously, the step linked to the source code for [this sanitizer](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb). However, more recently the [link has been removed](https://github.com/github/markup/commit/56a58500418779ee3e06db2bfcd86654acbf2ce7). If they are using something new and different, presumably it is even stricter that the old one.

Regardless, looking at the source code for the old sanitizer, it is clear that neither `<link>` nor `<canvas>` tags are included in the whitelist of allowed tags and therefore they would be completely removed from the document. And this makes sense, as both types of tags could be used to run third party code on GitHub's site, which would a serious security vulnerability.

If you want to publish something like this, you need to do so on a site which you have complete control over. If you want to stick with GitHub, you might want to look at GitHub Pages as an option.

Comment: Wow, excellent answer! Thanks for linking all the information, too, this is going to be really important for the future. Do you think I could get this to work using something other than the “canvas” tag? Something on Github’s white list?

Comment: If you can do it without any SVG, CSS or JavaScript, I suppose it could be possible, but if you need any one of those, then no, it is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that would be an option.  Do you know of any resources that can help me get started with Github Pages?  Like, tutorials, reference manuals, etc.?  Because I started trying to use it and it seems a little daunting XD